# Calculation of the top Chern class of spinor bundle over $S^{2n}$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, spin-geometry

It's well known that for a complex vector bundle $E$, we have

$$c_n(E)=e_n(E_\mathbb{R}) $$

**But I'm very curious about the relationship between the top Chern class of spinor bundle and the Euler class of tangent bundle over the same even-dimensional sphere $S^{2n}$. Why is the top Chern class of spinor bundle over $S^{2n}$ is the non-zero multiple of Euler number of $S^{2n}$?**

Could you give me some help with the details? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Let $\Sigma \to S^{2n}$ be the spinor bundle, then one has \begin{align*}
e(TS^{2n}) &= \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(n-1)!} \left( c_n(\Sigma^+)-c_n(\Sigma^-) \right),\\
0 &= c_n(\Sigma).
\end{align*}

Proof: The Atiyah-Singer index theorem for spin manifolds $M^{2n}$ says
\begin{align*}
 \chi(M) &= (-1)^{n}\int_M \hat{A}(TM)ch(\Sigma^+ - \Sigma^-)=\int_M e(TM) \\
 sign(M) &= \int_M \hat{A}(TM)ch(\Sigma) = \int_M L(TM)
\end{align*}
Since $M=S^{2n}$ has stably trivial tangent bundle one has $\hat{A}(TM) = 1 = L(TM)$. The only thing contributing to the first integral is some rational multiple of $c_n(\Sigma^+) - c_n(\Sigma^-)$.

Now I claim for any complex vector bundle $E \to S^{2n}$ one has
$$ch(E) = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} c_n(E).$$

To see this, let $x_1,...,x_n$ denote chern roots for $E$. We have by definition $$ch(E)[S^{2n}]= \left( \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} e^{x_i}\right) [S^{2n}] = \frac{1}{n!}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i^n\right)[S^{2n}].$$

Now we have to search for the coefficient of $c_n$ in the (unique) polynomial $P \in \mathbb{Z}[c_1,...,c_n]$ with $$P(c_1,\ldots,c_n)= x_1^n + \ldots + x_n^n$$ (where $c_i$ is the $i$-th elemtary symmetric polynomial in $n$ variables). Specializing to negatives of roots of unity namely
$$T^n - 1 = (T + x_1)...(T+x_n) = T^n + c_{1} T^{n-1} + ... + c_{n-1} T +c_n$$ we can see that this coefficient is $- (-1)^n n$.

**EDIT: Alternative** Without the Index theorem one can show (using the splitting principle) that for any real spin vector bundle $E$ of even rank $2r$
$$ ch(\Sigma^+(E) - \Sigma^-(E)) = \prod\limits_{i=1}^{r} (e^{-x_i/2} - e^{x_i/2}) $$
where $x_i$ are the chern roots of $E \otimes \mathbb{C}$. The euler class $e(E) = x_1 ... x_n$ divides this expression and one has (by definition)
$$ch(\Sigma^+(E)- \Sigma^-(E)) = (-1)^r e(E) \hat{A}(E)^{-1}$$
If $E$ is stabily trivial one has $\hat{A}(E) = 1$ and we are again left with determining $ch(\Sigma^+(E) - \Sigma^-(E))$ in degree $2r$.
Analogously $$ ch(\Sigma(E)^+ + \Sigma^-(E)) = \prod(e^{-x_i/2} + e^{x_i/2}) = \prod (2 + \frac{1}{4}x_i^2 + ... )$$
can be expressed only in Pontrjagin classes of $E$, so in the stably trivial case every chern class of the  spinor bundle has to vanish.

As a reference: Chapter III, § 11 & 12 in *Spin Geometry* by Lawson and Michelsohn.

Comment: We all know by Atiyah-Singer Index that $\chi(M)=\int_M e(TM)$, and it actually the Chern -Gauss-Bonnet formula, but I'm a little confused with $\chi(M)=\int_M\widehat{A}(TM)ch(\Sigma^+-\Sigma^-)$, why does it hold? Is it also from the Atiyah-Singer index theorem? If so, is here $\chi(M)$ the analytical index of which operator?

Comment: The Chern-Gauss-Bonnet theorem can be derived by plugging in the Hodge-de Rham operator $d + d^*$ (mapping from even to odd forms). The (maybe nontrivial) intermediate step is, that for spin manifolds the Hodge-de Rham operator is the spin dirac operator twisted by $\Sigma^+ - \Sigma^-$. I will add a nice reference for this to my answer. I believe,  the equation $\hat{A}(TM) ^{-1} e(TM) = ch(\Sigma^+ - \Sigma^-)$ is  'pre-Index Theorem' and probably due to Hirzebruch (maybe in the differentiable Riemann-Roch theorems).

Comment: I'm a little confused. Could you please explain the nontrivial intermediate step more explicitly?  What's the meaning that the spin operator is twisted by $\Sigma^+-\Sigma^-$? Is there some reference to this? Thanks

Comment: The top Chern class of any complex spinor bundle over the sphere is zero? How to see it in your above proof?@Jonas

Comment: I added a reference and an alternative calculation to my answer. I also noticed some sign trouble if $2n \neq 0$ mod $4$. I am thankful for any proposed corrections. For "the spin operator twisted by..." checkout Chapter II, § 5,6,7 of the reference.

Comment: Excuse me, how about my calculation in the link? Thanks in advance  @Jonas
 https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410288/calculation-about-chern-character-in-a-special-setting

Answer (score 2):

I will present an explicit calculation using Chern-Weil theory, which makes an amusing use of [Legendre's duplication formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem) for the gamma function.

The Chern character form of a vector bundle $E$ with connection $\nabla$ and curvature tensor $R^\nabla$ is
$$
\mathrm{ch}(E) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \mathrm{tr}(R^\nabla)^k.
$$
On the $2n$-sphere, only the $n$-th summand survives.

On a general Riemannian manifold, the curvature of the spinor bundle is
$$R^\Sigma(X, Y) \psi = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{ij=1}^m \langle R(X, Y) e_i, e_j\rangle e_i \cdot e_j,$$
where $R$ is the Riemann tensor (of the tangent bundle), $X$, $Y$ are vector fields and $e_1, \dots, e_m$ is a local ON-frame.
For the round sphere $S^m$, we have $R(X, Y) Z = \langle Y, Z\rangle X - \langle X, Z\rangle Y$, hence
$$
\sum_{ij=1}^{m}\langle R(X, Y) e_i, e_j\rangle e_i \cdot e_j
= \sum_{ij=1}^m\bigl(\langle Y, e_i\rangle \langle X e_j\rangle - \langle X, e_i\rangle \langle Y e_j\rangle\bigr)e_i \cdot e_j = X \cdot Y - Y \cdot X.
$$
We now use the general formula
$$
(\theta_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \theta_k)(X_1, \dots, X_{2k}) = \frac{1}{2^k}\sum_{\sigma \in S_{2k}} \mathrm{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^k \theta_i(X_{\sigma_{2i-1}}, X_{\sigma_{2i}})
$$
for the wedge product of $2$-forms $\theta_1, \dots, \theta_k$, which can be easily shown using induction.
We then get on $S^m = S^{2n}$ that
$$
(R^\Sigma)^{2n}(e_1, \dots, e_{2n})
  = \frac{1}{4^n \cdot 2^n} \sum_{\sigma \in S_{2n}} \mathrm{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^{n} (e_{\sigma_{2i-1}} \cdot e_{\sigma_{2i}} - e_{\sigma_{2i}} \cdot e_{\sigma_{2i-1}})\\
  =\frac{1}{4^{n}} \sum_{\sigma \in S_{2n}}\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma) e_{\sigma_1} \cdots e_{\sigma_{2n}}
  = \frac{(2n)!}{4^{n}} e_1 \cdots e_{2n}.
$$
Here $e_1, \dots, e_{2n}$ is a positively oriented ON-basis of the tangent space.
Because $i^{n} e_1\cdots e_{2n}$ is the grading operator of $\Sigma S^{2n}$ and the even and odd chirality spinor spaces have equal dimension, we see that it has zero trace over the whole spinor bundle.
However, the grading operator is $\pm 1$ on $\Sigma^\pm S^{2n}$, we obtain
\begin{equation*}
  \mathrm{tr}_{\Sigma^\pm}(i^{n}e_1 \cdots e_{2n}) = \pm 2^{n-1},
\end{equation*}
as $\dim(\Sigma^\pm S^{2n}) = 2^{n-1}$.
We therefore get
$$
 \mathrm{tr}_{\Sigma^\pm}\big((iR^\Sigma)^{n}(e_1, \dots, e_{2n})\big) = \pm \frac{(2n)!}{4^{n}} \cdot 2^{n-1} = \pm \frac{(2n)!}{2^{n+1}},
$$
which implies that
$$
\mathrm{tr}_{\Sigma^\pm}(iR^\Sigma)^{n} = \pm \frac{(2n)!}{2^{n+1}} \cdot \mathrm{vol} = \pm \frac{2n \cdot \Gamma(2n)}{2^{n+1}} \cdot \mathrm{vol} ,
$$
where $\mathrm{vol} = e_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge e_{2n}$ is the volume form.
Therefore, the $2n$-form part of the Chern character form is
$$
  \mathrm{ch}_{2n}(R^{\Sigma^\pm}) =  \frac{1}{n!} \mathrm{tr}_{\Sigma^\pm } \left(\frac{i R^\nabla}{2\pi}\right)^{n} 
  = \pm \frac{1}{n\cdot \Gamma(n)}  \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n}}\frac{2n \cdot \Gamma(2n)}{2^{n+1}} \cdot \mathrm{vol} \\
  = \pm \frac{\Gamma(2n)}{ \Gamma(n)}  \frac{1}{2^{2n} \pi^{n}} \cdot \mathrm{vol}.
$$
Integrating over the sphere, we get
$$
\int_{S^n} \mathrm{ch}(R^{\Sigma^\pm}) = \pm \frac{\Gamma(2n)}{ \Gamma(n)}  \frac{1}{2^{2n} \pi^{n}} \cdot \underbrace{\frac{2 \pi^{(2n+1)/2}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{2n+1}{2}\right)}}_{=\mathrm{vol}(S^{2n})}
= \pm \frac{\Gamma(2n)}{\Gamma(n)\Gamma(n+1/2)} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2^{2n-1}}.
$$
At this point, the right hand side looks rather hopeless, but then Legendre's duplication formula saves the day and states that the whole mess is just $\pm 1$.

Another explicit calculation can be found in [these notes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.03502.pdf) by Baum and Erp, see section 2.11. They realize the spinor bundle as a subbundle of a trivial bundle using a certain projection-valued function, but ultimately, the calculations are very similar and also use the duplication formula in the very last step of the proof (see the proof of Prop. 6 on p.10).